When are kubectl describe pod Restart Counts from?
When are microk8s kubectl describe pod -n <pod_name> Restart Counts from?
I see restart counts in the results at:
Containers.App-Name.Restart Count
For example see these results:
### microk8s kubectl describe pod -n kube-system hostpath-provisioner-566686b959-pmtw5
Name:         hostpath-provisioner-566686b959-pmtw5
Namespace:    kube-system
Priority:     0
Node:         ipc/192.168.1.101
Start Time:   Wed, 03 Aug 2022 10:10:26 +0000
Labels:       k8s-app=hostpath-provisioner
              pod-template-hash=566686b959
Annotations:  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.1.206.150/32
              cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.1.206.150/32
Status:       Running
IP:           10.1.206.150
IPs:
  IP:           10.1.206.150
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/hostpath-provisioner-566686b959
Containers:
  hostpath-provisioner:
    Container ID:   containerd://f32ed83a49dc15cc4f92c4fb03685b75117436e42345364d29e0a908633cd1c7
    Image:          cdkbot/hostpath-provisioner:1.1.0
    Image ID:       docker.io/cdkbot/hostpath-provisioner@sha256:317ed1b7324dc5f20db5dfdc0647a26a1ac44df426e9caad9cfdd6ba84c47697
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 06 Nov 2024 19:54:08 +0000
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Unknown
      Exit Code:    255
      Started:      Wed, 02 Oct 2024 22:40:48 +0000
      Finished:     Wed, 06 Nov 2024 19:53:09 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  68
    Environment:
      NODE_NAME:   (v1:spec.nodeName)
      PV_DIR:     /var/snap/microk8s/common/default-storage
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-d2s6c (ro)
      /var/snap/microk8s/common/default-storage from pv-volume (rw)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  pv-volume:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /var/snap/microk8s/common/default-storage
    HostPathType:  
  kube-api-access-d2s6c:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:                      <none>

But when are restarts counted from?
I don't see that answer in the kubectl describe pod docs here.

As the tag description suggests, this question may be for https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Refer to this document which might be helpful for you.

kubectl describe ... output is (mostly) just reformatted output from the Kubernetes API, which in turn is typically described in YAML.  kubectl get pod kubectl describe pod -n kube-system hostpath-provisioner-566686b959-pmtw5 -o yaml will give you that lower-level (but still readable) output.
All of the official Kubernetes API is documented.  A Pod and all of its various fields have their own page, and that more specifically includes a PodStatus object that you'd see if you were working in a typed language SDK (in Go for example there is a corev1.PodStatus struct).  The status: information includes both information on the Pod as a whole and also each individual container.
The restart count in your output seems to be tied to a specific container, so in that YAML output I'd look for
status:
  containerStatuses:
    - name: hostpath-provisioner
      restartCount: 68

In the API documentation, search for the nested path containerStatuses.restartCount, there doesn't seem to be a direct link.  In the generated Go SDK, the object and field docstrings are extracted from the API documentation, and your IDE can also show these field properties.
The number counts the number of times the container has restarted, since the Pod was initially created (part of the standard object metadata, .metadata.creationTimestamp).  For this container, the main container process has exited 68 times, and every time the cluster infrastructure has restarted it.  That is often but not necessarily a bug in your program (are you missing an exception handler in your main loop?).  It looks like it did run for a full month before exiting.

So I know what Restart Count is a measure of, my questions asks when they are counted from. What is the answer to my question? Which field has this info?

.status.containerStatuses[].restartCount is it.

When is a timestamp not an integer. I am not asking where in the payload restart count is located. I am asking after which timestamp restart counting begins.

"When" is since the Pod was initially created.  I've added that detail to the last paragraph of the answer.

It also looks like Start Time contains the same info

The restart count is the number of times a container in the pod has been restarted. In this case, hostpath-provisioner:1.1.0 has been restarted 68 times. If you had another container running in the pod, you would be able to see it's restart count separately. A restart happens when the container exits either due to an error or failure or because the application code explicitly defined an exit command. It can also happen if a liveness/startup probe fails where Kubernetes will forcibly restart the container. Since pods (unlike jobs) are designed to run forever, the container will keep restarting every time it exits.

So I know what Restart Count is a measure of, my questions asks when they are counted from. What is the answer to my question? Which field has this info?

When is whenever the pod first started
